# Compression in Apacge Ignite

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

Is there any data compression available in Apache Ignite? Or can we use any plugins for compression mainly to reduce the storage consumption.

Answer (score 4):

There is no data compression implemented in Ignite right now. But there is an enhancement proposal written for it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-20%3A+Data+Compression+in+Ignite

So, it would be a good feature, and it's going to be implemented in future.

Right now you can try to tune WAL archive size to reduce disk consumption: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log